# Reading Tasks in VSTO for MS-Project

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I'm trying to create a vsto add-in for project and I'm following this tutorial from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668209.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1/)

```
 void Application_NewProject(Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project pj)
        {
            MSProject.Task newTask = pj.Tasks.Add
                ("This text was added by using code", missing);
            newTask.Start = DateTime.Now;
            newTask.Duration = "3";
            newTask.ResourceNames = "Rob Caron, Kelly Krout";
        }
```

In this part they teach how to create a task. Now I would like to read tasks from an existing project but I haven't found examples online. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many c# examples for Microsoft Project. Look for VBA examples and translate as necessary. Here's the [documentation for the object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/object-model-project). Scroll down for the `Task` object to view its properties and methods.

Read through [SO posts with the ms-project tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) to see code examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I found to read tasks:

```
// Get the active project
public static MSProject.Project ActiveProject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;

    // Iterating over tasks in active project
    foreach (MSProject.Task oSubTask in ActiveProject.Tasks)
     {
        // Do something with the task
     }

    // If you want a particular task, set the index and choose the field
    string name = ActiveProject.Tasks[1].Name;
```